# why counter code add extra line every count?

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, counter

what is wrong with this code 
it adds extra line each time it count up or down 
how can i prevent that and why it's happening ?

```
def counter(start, stop):
    x = start
    if start > stop:
        return_string = "Counting down: "
        while x >= stop:
            return_string += str(x)
            x = x-1 
            if start != stop:
                return_string += ","
            print(return_string)
    else:
        return_string = "Counting up: "
        while x <= stop:
            return_string += str(x)
            x = x + 1 
            if start != stop:
                return_string += ","
            print(return_string)
    return return_string

print(counter(1, 10)) # Should be "Counting up: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10"
print(counter(2, 1)) # Should be "Counting down: 2,1"
print(counter(5, 5)) # Should be "Counting up: 5"
```

Comment: *"adds extra line each time it count up or down"*. Each time in loop you print. Do you see they are related?

Comment: Just remove the `print` statements in your function. You might also want to `return return_string.rstrip(',')` to trim a trailing comma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this :

```
def counter(start, stop):
    x = start
    if start > stop:
        return_string = "Counting down: "
        while x >= stop:
            return_string += str(x)
            x = x-1
            if start != stop:
                return_string += ","
        print(return_string)
    else:
        return_string = "Counting up: "
        while x <= stop:
            return_string += str(x)
            x = x + 1
            if start != stop:
                return_string += ","
        print(return_string)
    return return_string
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def counter(start, stop):
    x = start 
    if x>stop:
        return_string = "Counting down: "
        while x >= stop:
            return_string += str(x) 
        if x>stop:
            return_string += "," 
            x = x - 1
        else:
            return_string = "Counting up: " 
            while x <= stop: 
                return_string += str(x) 
                if x<stop:
                    return_string += "," 
                    x = x + 1
        return return_string
```

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
def counter(start, stop):
x = start
if start > stop:
    return_string = "Counting down: "
    while x >= stop:
        return_string += str(x)
        x = x-1
        if x >= stop:
            return_string += ","
else:
    return_string = "Counting up: "
    while x <= stop:
        return_string += str(x)
        x = x + 1
        if x <= stop:
            return_string += ","
return return_string
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def counter(start, stop):
    x = start
    if start > stop:
        return_string = "Counting down: "
        while x >= stop:
            return_string += str(x)
            if x != stop:
                return_string += ","
            x = x - 1

    else:
        return_string = "Counting up: "
    while x <= stop:
        return_string += str(x)
        if x != stop:
            return_string += ","
        x = x + 1

    return return_string
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

here's one :

```
def counter(start, stop):
    x = start
    if start>stop:

        return_string = "\"Counting down: "
        while x >= stop:
            return_string += str(x)
            x=x-1
            if x>=stop:
                return_string += ","
        return_string += '"'
    else:
        return_string = "\"Counting up: "
        while x <= stop:
            return_string += str(x)
            x=x+1
            if x<=stop:
                return_string += ","
        return_string += '"'
    return return_string
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code right here.
This will print out the results without the trailing commas.

```
def counter(start, stop):
x = start
if x > stop:
    return_string = "Counting down: "
    while x >= stop:
        return_string += str(x)
        x = x-1
        if start != stop:
            return_string += ","
            return_string.rstrip(',')
else:
    return_string = "Counting up: "
    while x <= stop:
        return_string += str(x)
        x = x + 1
        if start != stop:
            return_string += ","
return return_string.rstrip(',')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def counter(start, stop):
x = start
if start > stop:
    return_string = "Counting down: "
    while x >= stop:
        return_string += str(x)
        if x != stop :
            return_string += ","
        x -= 1
else:
    return_string = "Counting up: "
    while x <= stop:
        return_string += str(x)
        if x != stop:
            return_string += ","
        x += 1
return return_string

print(counter(1, 10)) # Should be "Counting up: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10"
print(counter(2, 1)) # Should be "Counting down: 2,1"
print(counter(5, 5)) # Should be "Counting up: 5"
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

#this will work

```
def counter(start, stop):
    x = start
    if start > stop:
        return_string = "Counting down: "
        while x >= stop:
            return_string += str(x)
                if x != stop :
                    return_string += ","
                x = x - 1
        
    else:
         return_string = "Counting up: "
         while x <= stop:
             return_string += str(x)
             if x != stop:
                   return_string += ","
             x = x + 1
        
    return return_string
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def counter(start, stop):
    x = start
    if x> stop:
        return_string = "Counting down: "
        while x >= stop:
            return_string += str(x)
            if x >= stop:
                return_string += ","
            x-=1
   else:
        return_string = "Counting up: "
        while x <= stop:
           return_string += str(x)
        
            if x <= stop:
                return_string += ","
            x+=1
    return return_string
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).